# Is it safe to install these V Brakes? Arms don't sit flush with bosses

Tags: shimano, brakes

Replacing my old V Brakes, got sold some Shimano BR-T4000s.

What I found is they don't sit quite flush on the bosses. There's an internal ring that's a bit larger, that ring is just a bit deeper on the old breaks, and just a bit shorter on the Shimanos. While the pin for the spring fits in the hole, there's just this like 5mm gap between the brake and the base. The boss also doesn't quite make it through to the other side like they did on the old brakes, and the included bolt is a bit shorter.

Is it safe to install these? Or do I just have mismatched parts?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate question but I couldn't find it.

It's fine. What you're looking at is the old brake pivots directly on the stud, but the new one mounts on the stud and has its own integral pivot. On the old one, you tighten the bolt very gently so you don't mushroom the post because the bolt is bottoming against the tip of the post. On the integral type, tighten it pretty good (8-10Nm). They both go on the same posts.

Comment: I agree about the integral pivot, but the third photo also looks like the brake arm could go onto the pivot further.  It looks like the spring hasn't engaged with any of the three holes, though a later photo shows it did.